# Android Studio crashed with jre fatal error on ubuntu system

Tags: java, android-studio

Last days I have started encountering with problem that my Android Studio IDE always crashing as long as I manually add "ulimit -c unlimited" using terminal.
How can I fix it permanently?

Here is log:

```
 # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:


# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_242) (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.242-b3-6222593 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x897d37]  ParNewGeneration::copy_to_survivor_space_avoiding_promotion_undo(ParScanThreadState*, oopDesc*, unsigned long, markOopDesc*)+0x37
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
```

Comment: Have you tried using a newer version of Java?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I did not. my work coworkers use the same version but everything ok for them

Comment: The problem was with RAM modules. After changin ram the problem does not occur anymore